# How to disconnect from a WiFi and connect to a wifi whose SSID and password is available?

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native, native-module

I am trying to disconnect from a WiFi and connect to a different wifi which is in access mode and I have to connect to it in order to configure the properties. Is there anyway I can do this?

I found a medium article online.

https://medium.com/woost/programatically-connecting-to-wifi-networks-in-react-native-on-ios-11-6103b726c3b0

I have tried to use Native Modules but I am not able to find anything for Android. Is there some library I can use to do this?